# Random Variables converge weakly in $ L^{1}(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{ P } )$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems

Suppose $X_n$, $n=1,2,... $ and $X$ are random variables defined on probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{ P } )$. They have bounded first moments.
Assume that $X_n \geq 0$  almost surely, $\mathbb{E}X_n = 1$ and $\mathbb{E}(X_n \log X_n) \leq 1$. Assume that for every bounded random variable $Y$, $\mathbb{E}(X_nY)\rightarrow \mathbb{E}(XY) $ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Show that:
$X_n \rightarrow X$ in probability and $\mathbb{E}(X\log X) \leq 1$.

In this problem, we know that $X_n,X \in L^{1}(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{ P })$, and $X_n$ converges weakly to $X$ in $L^{1}(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{ P })$, we need to deduce that $X_n$ converges in probability. Currently, I have no idea of this problem. Could anyone give me some hints?

Comment: Are you explicitly asked to prove that $X_n \to X$ in probability or is it something you think you need in order to prove the second part (namely $\mathbb E[X \log X] \le 1$)? I'm asking because you can directly prove the second part without the first.

Comment: Yes, the problem directly asked me to prove that $\mathbb{E}(X log X) \leq 1 $, but I was given a hint that first prove converge in probability and then prove the final consequence, so I was stuck here for a long time.